# Redirect customers after leaving woocommerce product review

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, comments

I am trying to redirect users to a thank you page after leaving a product review in woocommerce. I know the code

```
  add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
    function redirect_after_comment($location)
    {
    return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    }
```

will redirect all comments to a location, but I can't seem to find a filter or hook to specify only woocommerce product reviews. Has anyone done this before? Ideally I would just like to redirect to a standard wordpress page so I can add options and features to that pages template file in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`comment_post_redirect`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comment_post_redirect?version=4.1&file=wp-comments-post.php) filter has a second parameter. This parameter is the `$comment` object from which we can grab the post's ID. With the post's ID you can test for `post_type` and adjust the returned variable accordingly.

```
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment', 10, 2 );

function redirect_after_comment( $location, $comment ){
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;

    // product-only comment redirects
    if( 'product' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ){
        $location = 'http://www.woothemes.com';
    }
    return $location;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly doing development, but once I moved to the production enviroment, which is wpgengine(staging->Live) i get a white page when clicking the submit button to leave a review. I'll keep looking, but this did answer my question.

Comment: If you get a White Screen of Death then you should [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks - I enabled debugging - unfortunately it doesn't give me anything. I still get the white screen of death on the (wp-comments-post.php?wpe-comment-post= ) url. I use wpengine, so I am assuming it has something to do with a security setting somewhere.

Comment: try `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` that will put debug errors in a log in case they aren't being displayed properly. Also check your browser's developer console for script errors. And if works in WPEngine's staging area but not live, then try contacting their support.

Comment: So I found the issue after all your help. The comment form is calling the post url as the following: `<form action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-comments-post.php' ); ?>"` Where my client's website is using nonhttps urls everywhere except the woocommerce urls. So this is making its call the url as  `https://website.com/wp-comments-post.php`, where it is white screen of deathing. I modified the core file for a moment to test the theory and it worked, so once I can figure out how to modify the form action url outside of the wp-includes where it is safe, this can finally come to an end.

Comment: Well finding the issue is the first step in solving it. That's why I pushed the debug so hard. I would suggest posting this new issue as it's own question.

Comment: Can I just add, this hook won't work if you don't specify the little `2` at the end of the function call to specify how many parameters are to be passed to the hook. The default is `1` and this means your function won't get the comment object passed to it.